# Linux stuck at boot after updating opensuse tumbleweed

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse, opencl

I installed opensuse tumbleweed, updated to newest version, installed amdgpu for opencl usages. Rebooted, worked correctly. Updated via "sudo zypper dup" and there were some kernel changes. Rebooted, and stuck at boot (see screenshot), last few messages mention amdgpu and drm so my guess is that there is something wrong with the amdgpu but I need the amdgpu for opencl. I have two gpu's installed: gigabyte radeon 6870 1GB (connected with display) and amd 5700 XT (not connected to any display). If I connect the display to 5700XT then the computer boots to konsole, no gui. The cpu does not have integrated graphics.

[image: boot log]

Any ideas what can I do to make this work?

I've booted previous snapshots and it worked correctly but after updating via "sudo zypper dup" it returns to the broken state.

Comment: you probably need to tell the kernel which GPU to use for the console.  You may be able to set that in the BIOS (see if there's any option for setting the primary GPU).  Or you may be able to override the BIOS's choice with kernel command-line options.  The following may help: [Select graphics card for console output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336114/select-graphics-card-for-console-output)

Comment: also, you probably need to explicitly configure X to use the same GPU, instead of relying on it to pick one.  This can be done by creating/modifying a `Device` section in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, configure it to use the PCI bus-id of the appropriate GPU.